# Keeping a user from clicking 'submit', before the form is valid

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a web form that uses a lot of JavaScript and ajax to determine if each field is valid. It gives warning messages on the fly to help the user know when there's a problem. I even use the "disable" feature on my submit button until everything is up to snuff. But here's the problem: All the event handling happens using the `onblur` feature. but when the last field is  filled out, the validation doesn't happen till the user clicks away from that field. but why would they? there's nothing left to do on the page but click submit, which they can't do until they click somewhere else, anywhere else, first (to set off the validation event). I'm trying to find a way around this. There has to be a way where they don't have to make that extra click. it just doesn't seem professional. Is there a standard way around this? Can the validation event be triggered each time the user types an individual letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate each field using onkeyup, and withhold your user notification to the onblur method so it doesn't get annoying. If all fields are valid at the onkeyup, enable the submit button.

Comment: This a start, but I think it's also possible to edit fields without the keyboard such as copy/paste with the mouse right menu or drag/drop so key events aren't the only way that fields can be changed.

Comment: Looks like you can also use the onChange event. This will ensure it gets called after every update.

Comment: It's my understanding that onchange only fires upon the field losing focus (if the contents has changed).  See [MDN reference info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange).

Comment: You're right, forgot about that part. I ended up using the onsubmit event and doing a final validation. For this you would have to leave the submit button enabled and add the onsubmit event to the form, just like Zach suggests.

Comment: perfect! That sounds like the right way to go with this. I'll just have to separate the notification code from the submit enable code

Answer (score 1):

The form node has an `onsubmit` event that will fire when the user tries to submit the form. You can use this to validate all of the form fields and decide whether to let the user submit the form. The general implementation is this:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    ...
</form>
```

And in your JavaScript function, you have to return true if the user can continue submitting the form, or false to cancel the user's request before the form is submitted.

(In Psuedo-code):

```
function validateForm(){
    if(formIsOkay){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: im using a separate script to controll this but i cant get it to stop the form from getting submited

Answer (score 0):

Given the limitations of {onChange, onKeyup, blur, etc} when it comes to handling copy/pasted or other edge cases I would probably add a timer to poll every 500ms or so and enable/disable the submit button:

```
window.setInterval(checkEnableSubmit, 500);

function checkEnableSubmit(){
   if(validateForm()){
       // enable submit button
   } 
}

function validateForm(){
     if(formIsOkay){
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

I'd still call validateForm() on the button click to avoid users invalidating data and submitting before the timer is called. Server side validation is a given but I'd like to avoid the bad submit if possible.